# ¿Como sincronizar las modificaciones que hacemos en el repo de nuestra maquina con el repo github?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Estoy siguiendo el [tutorial de openlassrooms sobre GitHub](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/gerer-son-code-avec-git-et-github/envoyer-son-code-sur-github) y no estoy capaz  sincronizar las modificaciones que hizo sobre la maquina con el repo sobre GitHub :

```
:~/Swiper_ProjetAutomatisation$ git commit -a -m "Initialise source code"
[master (root-commit) d41462a] Initialise source code
 1 file changed, 132 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 testPostreSQLPythonG.py
:~/Swiper_ProjetAutomatisation$ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

He leido [sobre StackOverflow una respuesta de Matt Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n/32238628) que me parece un poquito demasiado general para ayudarme. Propone Matt Clark,cuando `git remote -v` no devuelve nada, hacer :

```
$git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git
```

Si, en mi caso, `git remote -v` no devuelve nada, por una parte no sé que reemplazar en `git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git` y por otra parte el profesor sobre el tutorial nos dice no utilisar ssh por lo momento pero https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git` es una URI, que significa:

- `ssh://` -> protocolo ssh.
- `git@` -> usuario conexión ssh.
- `example.com` -> servidor.
- `:1234` -> puerto ssh.
- `/myRepo.git` -> carpeta dentro del servidor.

A partir del `ssh://`, el resto del String varía en función del protocolo.

Como tu usas `https://`, usarás las URIs en formato HTTP/HTTPS. Por ejemplo, para un servidor en github.com:

```
https://github.com/MiUsuario/MiRepositorio
```

También debería soportar que le añadas usuario y contraseña (lo último no es recomendado que lo pongas en el `remote`):

```
https://miUsuario@github.com/MiUsuario/MiRepositorio
https://miUsuario:miContraseña@github.com/MiUsuario/MiRepositorio
```

Comment: ¿Ha ? ¿Y que escribiera si no utiliso `remote` ? `git add origin ssh://antoine_comp@example.com:1234/Swiper_ProjetAutomatisation.git`

Comment: Exactamente lo mismo, cambia la URL del ssh por la del HTTPS.

Comment: ¿Y como puedo saber cual esta el servido y el puerto ? 
¿El de  por de arriba esta un ejemplo, no ?
Tengo `fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files
` con `:~/Swiper_ProjetAutomatisation$ git add origin https://antoine_comp@example.com:1234/Swiper_ProjetAutomatisat‌​ion.git
`

Comment: A ver, tú tienes que saber donde está el repositorio al que quieres subir los cambios. La URL con el protocolo SSH está para explicar que es sólo una URL normal y corriente, que basta con sustituir esa URL por la URL de tu servidor para que funcione. Normalmente no especificarás el puerto, y el usuario no es obligatorio (mira mi ejemplo de GitHub)

Comment: el repositorio al que quiero subir los cambios se llama `Swiper_ProjetAutomatisation`

Comment: A ver, si tienes un repositorio en github, ve a la página web del repositorio y dale al botón de "clone or download". Ésa es la URL del repositorio, sin nada más.